# PDF Viewer only show first page properly

Tags: android, pdf, webview

I want to make a PDF viewer using a WebView and Google Docs url.
However, for some reason it isn't showed properly when it reaches 2nd page and successive, except on Android 5.

Here is an image from Android 4.1.1:
http://oi57.tinypic.com/6rrbpy.jpg

And here other from Android 5.0.0:
http://oi62.tinypic.com/2vdlefm.jpg

Any idea why this happens?
Here is my code

```
public class PDFViewer extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.web_viewer);

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webViewSimple);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            if (progressDialog == null) {
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(PDFViewer.this);
                progressDialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                progressDialog.show();
            }
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                progressDialog = null;
            }
        }
    });

    String link=getIntent().getExtras().getString("link");
    myWebView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+link);
}
```

Comment: I tested on Android 4.4, 5.0 and later, Google Docs shows PDF files correctly.